# Exctract number and sum number from free text input, add to df

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, extract

I have a dataframe with a column that contains free text entries on years of education. From the free text entries I want to extract all of the numbers and sum them.

Example: data_en$educationTxt[1] gives "6 primary school 10 highschool"

With the following code I can extract both numbers and sum them.

```
library(stringr)
x <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(data_en$education[1], "[0-9A]+")[[1]])
x <- as.vector(x)
x <- sum(x)
```

However, I would ideally like to do this for all free text entries (i.e. each row) and subsequently add the results to the dataframe per row (i.e. in a variable such as data_en$educationNum). I'm a bit stuck on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply`:

```
data_en$educationNum <- sapply(str_extract_all(data_en$education, "[0-9]+"), 
       function(i) sum(as.numeric(i)))

data_en
#                        education educationNum
# 1 6 primary school 10 highschool           16
# 2 10 primary school 2 highschool           12
# 3                      no school            0
```

**Data**

```
data_en <- data.frame(education = c("6 primary school 10 highschool",
                      "10 primary school 2 highschool",
                      "no school"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `map` over the output of `str_extract_all`

```
x <- c('300 primary 1 underworld', '6 secondary 9 dungeon lab')

library(purrr)
map_dbl(str_extract_all(x, '\\d+'), ~ sum(as.numeric(.)))

# [1] 301  15
```